# Get remote file size via HTTP without downloading said file

Tags: iphone, web-services, file, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

Any way to get the size of a (remote, http) file without actually downloading it?

All other similar questions seem to revolve around grabbing the `expectedContentLength` from the `NSURLResponse` object in `didReceiveResponse:` but I don't want to download the file, I just want to know how big it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make HEAD request, it returns only headers with Content-Length header included.

```
~$ curl -I http://google.com/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Length: 219
...
```

Comment: Generally correct, but just in case the server sends Content-Length, it may not do this if the content length is unknown for it. But this is the best client can do.

Comment: Hm, seems NSURL is buggy with HEAD requests (at least according to http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/99348-head-request-using-nsurlconnection.html ) but I'll give that a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Content-Length also reports gzip compressed length, if compression is turned on on the server. Case in point, http://google.com/ is most definitely more than 219 bytes.